# Unable to "run" on Heroku

Tags: clojure, heroku

I have deployed a Clojure app to Heroku. When I run/request it I get an error: http://glowing-planet-168.herokuapp.com/. So now I want to start up a REPL to see if I can get some more info. But when I try it I get:

```
D:\Mijn documenten\My Dropbox\dev\clojure-projects\hebrewajax>heroku run lein repl

C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/heroku-2.2.4/lib/heroku/helpe
rs.rb:213:in ``': No such file or directory - tput cols (Errno::ENOENT)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/heroku-2.2.4/lib
/heroku/helpers.rb:213:in `get_terminal_environment'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/heroku-2.2.4/lib
/heroku/command/run.rb:16:in `index'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/heroku-2.2.4/lib
/heroku/command.rb:114:in `send'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/heroku-2.2.4/lib
/heroku/command.rb:114:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/heroku-2.2.4/bin
/heroku:14
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/bin/heroku:19:in `load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/bin/heroku:19
```

I get the same error when I do 'heroku run console'. I installed heroku using RailsInstaller.

I am running on Windows XP.

What could go wrong here? Some gem I have to installe besides heroku?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have experience with heroku or Windows, but it looks like you're missing the shell command 'tput', which is (in this case) used to get the width of your terminal window. If I understand correctly, you need to have Cygwin installed, which might have been installed with RailsInstaller. You might also need to install the 'ncurses' package which has the tput utility. Good luck!

Comment: I succeeded getting things to work using your answer and this page: http://flux88.com/2009/06/getting-started-with-heroku-on-windows/