# Unable to run console from heroku on Win

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, heroku, cygwin

I am having the same problem as posted here [Unable to "run" on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229560/unable-to-run-on-heroku)

As recommended in the resolution to the above posting, I already have Cygwin installed - not a fresh install as it has been sitting on my machine for a few months. Since all gems required by the app are installed and the test app is successfully deployed and working on Heroku I take it I don't have to do any additional (gems or otherwise) installation through the Cygwin window. When I run the command "heroku run rails console --app " on Cygwin it gives me the same error as I get when I run the command on a windows terminal -

```
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-2.2.4/lib/heroku/helpers.rb:213:in ``': No such file or directory - tput cols (Errno::ENOENT)
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-2.2.4/lib/heroku/helpers.rb:213:in `get_terminal_environment'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-2.2.4/lib/heroku/command/run.rb:16:in `index'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-2.2.4/lib/heroku/command.rb:114:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-2.2.4/bin/heroku:14:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby192/bin/heroku:19:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby192/bin/heroku:19:in `<main>'
```

Now the odd thing seems to be that Cygwin is referring paths through C:/ whereas I would expect it to take it from /cygdrive/c/. To verify that I ran a simple command "gem list" from rails app directory in Cygwin and sure enough I get this error

```
$ gem list
C:\Ruby192\bin\ruby.exe: No such file or directory -- /cygdrive/c/Ruby192/bin/gem (LoadError)
```

However if I run the same gem list command when I am in the C:\Ruby192\bin directory where ruby and gem commands are installed then the command runs fine and lists all my gems. Apparently somehow Cygwin is getting C:/ paths that it doesn't seem to know how to interpret.

It sounds like I am missing something basic about how to make Cygwin read these paths correctly.

Can't seem to find what am I missing here.

Thanks for your thoughts on how to resolve this.

-S

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to "run" on Heroku](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229560/unable-to-run-on-heroku) - please read the answer to that question more carefully (you need to install ncurses)

Answer (score 1):

There might be a better solution for this but reinstalling cygwin with ruby worked for me. More info:
http://benscheirman.com/2009/06/getting-started-with-heroku-on-windows

Answer (score 1):

For the path part of your question:

Up to date, native Windows executables (such as bundle, heroku, pik, rake, ruby, etc. ) can be 
used on Cygwin. However, you must say: `$ gem.bat list`. Or, in ~/.bashrc: `alias gem=gem.bat`.