# Ruby on Rails Tutorial Demo_App - rake db:migrate to Heroku not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, railstutorial.org

I'm doing Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorials and am having a bit of a problem with the final stage of the Demo App, that is, running the rake command on Heroku to migrate the database to the web.

The rake command with a --trace on it gives the following result:

```
$ heroku run rake db:migrate --trace
Running `rake db:migrate --trace` attached to terminal...
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36: command not found: tput cols
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36: command not found: tput lines
up, run.1
(in /app)
* Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:migrate
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- pg
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:227:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:9:in `postgresql_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:230:in `new_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:238:in `checkout_new_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:194:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:190:in `loop'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:190:in `block in checkout'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:189:in `checkout'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:96:in `connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:318:in `retrieve_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:97:in `retrieve_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:89:in `connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:486:in `initialize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:433:in `new'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:433:in `up'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:415:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:142:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `block in execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2051:in `invoke_task'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `block in top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2023:in `top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2001:in `block in run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
```

I thought that that 'command not found: tput' stuff at the start might have been down to something I modified (it looks like the word 'output' that got cut off) so I redid the entire chapter from the beginning, but ended up with the same result, so I don't think it's any changes I made to the code.

I'm using a Windows PC, running XP. Everything worked fine when run on the localhost and my Git Repository pushed to Heroku perfectly, so everything works except for this rake command. If ye want to see any of the other files, they're at: https://github.com/jimbobsweeney/demo_app

I'm very grateful in advance for any help on this. It's melting my brain.

Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have Cygwin installed? [This article](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/seinzumtode/20120120/1327062443) *(in Japanese)* mentions this error and points to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229560/unable-to-run-on-heroku) which suggests you make sure Cygwin and possibly ncurses is installed. A comment there links to [this article](http://benscheirman.com/2009/06/getting-started-with-heroku-on-windows) which may also have useful information.

It looks like the issue is that heroku is looking for the `tput` command in your shell which is not available *(which I believe comes with ncurses)*.

As for the stack trace, it looks like the `pg` gem is not in your `Gemfile` in a place the production environment will execute it. It's not necessary to install `pg` on Windows just to get the deploy working. Create a `:production` group in your `Gemfile` for this.

```
group :production do
  gem "pg", "~> 0.11.0"
end
```

You can learn more about groups in [the bundler docs](http://gembundler.com/groups.html).

Comment: Thanks very much @Deefour! I'm running Cygwin and reinstalled it to include ncurses, which sorted out the `tput` problem. However, the rest of the problem is still there, with the rake being aborted. I have been trying to install the PG gem this morning to see if it will help but haven't really got anywhere. Are there libraries used by the command that are included by default on OS X but have to be installed manually on Windows, I wonder?

Comment: I did this but the problem remained as it was. I first changed the Gemfile, then tried to rake. Then I tried to run a bundle install, which was fine until it reached `Installing pg (0.11.0) with native extensions
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... no`
It goes on to say `Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.`
I'll put the text of mkmf.log below.

Comment: mkmf.log (in the directory relating to pg v0.11.0) goes like this: `find_executable: checking for pg_config... -------------------- no

--------------------

find_header: checking for libpq-fe.h... -------------------- no

"gcc -E -I. -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/i386-cygwin -I.    -ggdb -O2 -pipe -fno-strict-aliasing     conftest.c -o conftest.i"
conftest.c:1:22: libpq-fe.h: No such file or directory
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include <libpq-fe.h>
/* end */

--------------------`

Comment: See the documentation link above. Groups are used to avoid this sort of issue. Since you don't want/need `pg` in **development**, put it in a `:production` group and run `bundle install --without production` to skip this group in your development environment. `Gemfile.lock` will still be properly updated for your deploy.

Comment: Thank you mate. I had actually done a `bundle install--without production` before and it went perfectly. The reason it didn't work was because I hadn't committed the changes! So for anyone reading this who's as big a n00b as I am, go 1) `git commit -am "Updated production group in Gemfile"` 2) `git push heroku master` and 3) `heroku run rake db:migrate`. Everything works. Much appreciated!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out. :)